# Remove query strings only on requests requiring PHP (ignoring static files and certain urls)

Tags: nginx, rewrite

One of my sites keeps getting spammed with fake URL requests containing query strings.

I have caching in place but unfortunately query strings are ignored. Now every time I get a flood of query string requests my server gets nailed due to an influx of hits to the database and PHP processing (I'm using wordpress) and my server becomes none-respondant.

How can I ignore/rewrite the requests containing query strings for any url that will be passed through to my backend but allow them for static files and certain urls (/search/, /wp-admin/, wp-login.php etc)?

My nginx setup

```
location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_index index.php;

        try_files $uri = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
    }


# Use cached or actual file if they exists, otherwise pass request to WordPress
location / {
        try_files /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
}
```

Is there an easy(ish) way of accomplishing this with rewrites? I'm shocked that I can't find hardly any other information on this on the internet (perhaps I'm not searching for the correct solution), I surely can't be the only one who is facing this issue.

How does everybody deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the trick...

```
http {

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=default_con:20m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=php:1m rate=2r/s;

location ~ \.php {

## LIMIT REQUESTS TO STOP SERVER GETTING NAILED ##
        limit_req zone=php burst=7 nodelay;
        limit_conn default_con 2;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain in more details how your solution works and what it does exactly? For example what is $binary_remote_addr and where it is defined?